# Why am I accumulating excessively?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, compare, accumulator

very confused noob over here. can anyone explain why i @ 12 and i @ 13 are accumulating? 
My function is supposed to look at two strings to see if the second string is contained in the first string. I'm doing this by looping through both strings and comparing the characters at that index from both String1 and String2. If the accumulator evaluates to the length of the shorter string, then the function will return 1 and print: 'it works.' Otherwise it will return 0.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int accum = 0;
    char string1[21];
    char string2[9];
    strcpy(string1, "The test for the lab");
    strcpy(string2, "The test");
    int j = (strlen(string1)-1);
    for(int i = 0; i<=j; i++){
        if(string1[i] == string2[i]){
            accum += 1;
            printf("accum is %d \n",accum);         
            printf("i is %d \n",i);
            printf("string1[i] is %c \n",string1[i]);
            printf("string2[i] is %c \n",string2[i]);           
        }
    }
if (accum == strlen(string2)){
    printf("it works!");
    return 1;
}
else
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
accum is 1 
i is 0 
string1[i] is T 
string2[i] is T 
accum is 2 
i is 1 
string1[i] is h 
string2[i] is h 
accum is 3 
i is 2 
string1[i] is e 
string2[i] is e 
accum is 4 
i is 3 
string1[i] is   
string2[i] is   
accum is 5 
i is 4 
string1[i] is t 
string2[i] is t 
accum is 6 
i is 5 
string1[i] is e 
string2[i] is e 
accum is 7 
i is 6 
string1[i] is s 
string2[i] is s 
accum is 8 
i is 7 
string1[i] is t 
string2[i] is t 
accum is 9 
i is 12 
string1[i] is   
string2[i] is   
accum is 10 
i is 13 
string1[i] is t 
string2[i] is t
```

help please!

Comment: When `i` is greater than `strlen(string2)`, you're reading outside that string. This causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You need to set `j` to the length of the shorter of the two strings.